# How to make statement work perfectly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Can I initialize Cx register with a variable value?
Such as shown below

```
MOV Cx, varaible
```

If no, then how to dynamically initialize Cx with a user-input value? Please help!

Comment: "a variable value" Show the definition for your 'variable.' "a user-input value" How are you inputting this variable?

Comment: are you talking about assembly language or inline assembly language?

Comment: Sir I have following code

.Data 
var DB ?

And inside MAIN PROC
MOV ah, 01
INT 21H

; then  I moved value from Al  register to variable named as var
MOV var, Al
 ; Then I INITIALIZED cx as follows

MOV Cx, var

Comment: I am talking about assembly language

Comment: But you said variables.  Variables in assembly language?  inline sure there are variables, because that is C or other, but assembly language, there are labels(addresses) (or immediates).

Comment: maybe i am not confirmed about name of the language.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about names, but about mental image. There are no variables in assembly.

For the machine there are just registers, memory, addresses, and accessing memory with instructions. *Variables* are logical construct of programmer, who decided to write his code in such way - that it will use memory as "variable". But if he decides to not, or makes a mistake, then it will not behave as variable, the machine does not care.

For example in your code, you allocate memory for "variable" in `.data` section:

```
.Data
var DB ?
```

This will translate into symbol `var`, which is effectively address into memory. It will also reserve single byte in the `.data` section, so anything next defined to land there will be allocated after that. If you will add on next line `var2 DB 13`, then the `var2` address will be equal to `var + 1`. You can also create several symbols with the same address, like this:

```
.Data
var:
var2:
    DB ?
```

With such definition both `var` and `var2` symbols point to the same memory address.

It may still look like your "variables" mental image is compatible with this, so I will demonstrate another difference between "just memory" and "variables":

```
MOV [var], AL      ; store value in AL into memory at address "var"
; your MOV var, AL without brackets works only in MASM/TASM assemblers
; but it is not valid Intel syntax, I will use brackets for every memory access
```

This writes the 8 bit value from `AL` into memory at address `var`. So far so good. Now you ask about:

```
MOV CX, [var]
```

This will compile and execute, but it will not work as expected. Because you did write only 8 bits into memory, and reserved only 1 byte for `var`. But `CX` is 16 bit register (composed from `CH` as high 8 bits and `CL` as low 8 bits), so this instruction will read TWO bytes from memory from address `var`. x86 is little-endian, so when CPU works with 16 bit value, it will map low 8 bits as first byte (offset +0), and high 8 bits as second byte (offset +1). So this will load `CL` with the value which was stored from `AL`, and `CH` with some value, which happens to be there in memory after the `var`. If you would add that `var2 DB 13` after `var`, then `CH` would be equal to value `13`, and thus the total `CX` value will be then `13*256 + <stored_AL>`. If stored `AL` was 7, then `CX = 3335` (or in hexadecimal formatting `0D07h`, which nicely shows the two byte values, `D` = 13, `7` = 7).

So if you want to correctly read the stored 8 bit value into `CX`, you have to extend it from 8 bits to 16 bits. If you work with 80386+ instruction set, there are specialized instructions for that:

```
MOVZX cx,BYTE PTR [var]    ; zero-extend value ("unsigned" arithmetic)
MOVSX cx,BYTE PTR [var]    ; sign-extend value ("signed" arithmetic)
```

For CPUs before 80386 you have to calculate such value, one possible way is:

```
XOR cx, cx     ; clear all 16bits of CX to zero
MOV cl, [var]  ; fetch only low 8 bits from memory
; CX is now zero-extended 16 bit value of [var] (like MOVZX)

MOV ch, [var]  ; fetch 8 bit value into upper 8 bits of CX
SAR cx, 8      ; use right shift by 8 bits to sign-extend the value
; CX is now sign-extended 16 bit value of [var] (like MOVSX)
; this code is not optimal on 586+ CPUs, but then use MOVSX
```

So that's the major difference between "just memory" and "variables", the assembly will not guard you, and it will let you read/write memory outside of variables, it's your task to write correct code, and think about data size, and allocate/reserve enough memory. Plus do all the pointer math manually, i.e. if you want to create array of words (16 bits values), then you will have to scale index by *2 to calculate the correct byte address (while C/C++ will hide the pointer math from you, so you do just [i], and the *2 is done internally by compiler).

Comment: I like to think of variables the way a compiler does, as logical entities not tied to a specific location.  So a variable can be in a register in some parts of a function, and in memory in other parts.  I really dislike the common asm terminology of only using "variable" to describe static storage with a label.  So +1 for arguing against that, even though you don't talk about keeping variables in registers.